# suggest helper method for this Java Generics piece of code please

Tags: java, generics, java-6, helpermethods

I accidentally wrote this piece of code .

```
   static List<Integer> foo(List<Integer> fillthis,List<? super Integer> readlist){
      for(Object i:readList){
        if(i instanceof Integer)
            fillthis.add(i);
      }
      return fillthis;
    }
```

As you can see, it basically takes a list of Integer and another List of Integer or any of its supertype, say a List of Object; Then from the 'readList' it extracts every int value and puts it into the given int List 'fillthis' 
I used List because even a List or List can contain an integer

Ofcourse, it won't compile because compiler won't let an unverified value from 'readList' into a pure int List 'fillthis' .
So it ends up giving me typical error :

```
actual argument Object cannot be converted to Integer by method invocation conversion
```

But, tend to think of it, this is a perfectly reasonable piece of code if only one can get around this with the help of helper methods 
Can someone please help ? I have tried my wits ends

THANK YOU VERY MUCH :)

EDIT ------------------

Thanks Meindratheal, 
but can anyone suggest a helper method for this one , incase if I don't wish to typecast
because 
a helper method like

```
static <T,U super T> List<T> foo(List<T> fillthis,List<U> readList);
```

won't work 
as generics don't allow 'super' in type parameter list. it only allows extends
also ,is there even a helpermethod for this one.

Please do suggest :)

---

UPDATE

---

Braj, I don't know how it affects what kind of list I am passing!
Ofcourse, I could follow your advice and pass on a List
and TBH, this code isn't a piece of any serious software design
BUT DEAR, this very simple question does challenge our knowledge of java generics

Maybe read my code again above 
and I guess you know already what my question is

Ok fine, 
lets say I have

```
public static void main(String[] args){
   List<Integer> lint=Arrays.asList(1,2,3);
   List<Object> lobj=new List<Object>();
   lobj.add(new Object());
   lobj.add(new Integer(4)); /*will compile perfectly. had I used List<? super Integer> instead of List<Integer>, I can't pass lobj to extract this value of 4. Clear?? */
   foo(lint,lobj);
}
```

**The question is simple :Can we create a helper method to make this method work exactly like it is ??**

Comment: Hi @Kayaman thanks for taking interest in answering my question :)
The thing is it takes first parameter as List of Integer and second parameter is list of Integer OR list of any supertype of Integer[say a Number or Object] because a list of Number or Object can also contain an integer value
I hope its clear now

Answer (score 1):

You have to cast `i` to Integer:

```
static List<Integer> foo(List<Integer> fillthis,List<? super Integer> readlist){
    for(Object i:readList){
        if(i instanceof Integer)
            fillthis.add((Integer) i);
    }
    return fillthis;
}
```

Comment: Meindratheal , thanks for answering. I am sorry I couldn't give your answers a +1 as I don't have required points. 
also I am wondering now what Kayaman meant by 'not good generic code' ?
is he referring to my code or yours ? 
@Kayaman please answer :D

Answer (score 0):

**use `List<Number>` instead of `List<? super Integer>` to make it more clear.**

Simply use in this way.

```
static List<Integer> foo(List<Integer> fillthis, List<Number> readlist) {
    for (Number i : readlist) {
        if (i instanceof Integer)
            fillthis.add(i.intValue());
    }
    return fillthis;
}
```

Comment: What do you understand by `? super Integer`? Why are you using it?  What type of values do you have in `readlist`?

Comment: Hi Braj,well I used List<? super Integer> in place of List<Integer> because List<? super Integer> basically means List<Object> or List<Number>,do you agree?
But then List<Object> OR List<Number> CAN CONTAIN an Integer value because Integer is subclass of both Object and Number, agree?
So,my second parameter is List<? super Integer> so that user can also extract Integer values from a list of, say List<Object>
Had I used just List<Integer> inplace of List<? super Integer>,I couldn't pass List<Object> or List<Number> & hence integer values from these lists couldn't be extracted
Clear I hope ??

Comment: @Sarabjeet OK your requirement is clear now. I hope you got the answer too.

Comment: actually I didn't the way I wanted to
HELPER METHOD ANYONE ? :)

Comment: Dear, I already knew that even before asking for help here
You keep asking me to narrow down the scope of my function. I am just asking you if you can suggest me a helper method for same 
:D
I hope you're aware of helper methods in java generics

Comment: @Sarabjeet Let me try to find out. Working on it.

Comment: Braj, what you think ? is a helper method for my method possible ??

like for instance this simple example
`void foo(List<?> i) {`
        `i.set(0, i.get(0));`
    `}`
will not compile

So helper method :
`private <T> void fooHelper(List<T> l) {
        l.set(0, l.get(0));
    }`

and invoked by original method as 
`void foo(List<?> i) {
        fooHelper(i);
    }`
**Yes please work on it. Hopefully waiting for your answer :)**

Comment: Can you provide some sample code. What type of List are you passing in helper method? Add it in your post.